# MATLAB open read-only copy of the same file

Tags: matlab, editor

I have files with multiple hundred lines and I would like to open a read-only copy of the same file, which I am editing, to be able to hold that file at a function, which already works, and implement another different, but in some ways similar function to the actual file being edited in order to spare myself from the horrible up-and-down scrolling of the screen.

I am on a locked win-system, so don't have any reasonable other editor to do that, like notepad++.

Do you know how to open another instance of the same file in matlab? Preferably open it read-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matlab editor supports split screen (in the newer versions, you can go to the View menu and select "left/right", "up/down" (2015a and onwards: "top/bottom"), "custom"); could you split your file into two scripts, and work on one part in one window and another part in another? If not, you could make a copy of the file as your read only version? Alternatively, a little more work:

You could make a symlink to the original version in the system command line (or use the matlab `system` command):

`mklink MyLinkFile.m MyOriginalFile.m /H`

and open both of these in the editor. When you make changes and save one, and click on the other window, the changes will appear.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! Actually, just going like your first hint: view-"up/down" satisfies my requirement! I just hadn't realized this feature.

Comment: Since Matlab R2013a simultaneously syncs the two open files in the split-window mode / or they are the same thing - that's why I don't need the read-only feature, as there is no way I can accidentally spoil my code, as I see the changes to one window simultaneously in the other.